# Jquery selector for nummer patterns

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i match 'i' with 1 3 5 6 9 10 to get something like this using JS (jquery) !?

[image]

```
 <div class="questions">
    <ul>
        <li class="cat_definition">
            <div class="question">What is ‘hair mass’?</div>
        </li>
        <li class="light cat_definition">
            <div class="question">What is the difference between 'hair mass' and 'hair volume'?</div>
        </li>
        <li class="light cat_ingredients clear">
            <div class="question">What does the Densify range smell like?</div>
        </li>
        <li class="cat_routine">
            <div class="question">How often should I use Densify products?</div>
        </li>
        <li class="cat_routine clear">
            <div class="question">How many consecutive days do the products need to be used to achieve the desired effect?</div>
        </li>   
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
    .questions li{
    width : 50%;
    float : left;
    background:#f00;
}

.questions li:nth-child(4n+1),
.questions li:nth-child(4n+4){
    background : #fff;
}
.questions li:nth-child(odd){
    clear : both;
}
```

I have to put the 'li' blocks side by side with different colors like this image. I can't use css3 and i can't add classes on html. i have to select the blocks in javascript and add new classes for black boxes.

See what i have tried : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prakashapkota/Lfev6sx9/)

Comment: Post your HTML. Currently not enough information to answer

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried?

Comment: That can be done in CSS if you don't support IE8 and below.

Comment: What is `i`? How do those numbers relate to the question? What is that graphic? Has it something to do with your question? If yes, what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is fairly easy in CSS, You have to play with the `nth-child`. Using those CSS work :

```
.questions li{
    width : 50%;
    float : left;
    background:#f00;
}

.questions li:nth-child(4n+1),
.questions li:nth-child(4n+4){
    background : #fff;
}
.questions li:nth-child(odd){
    clear : both;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/34oj7rhc/

The problem is browser support. `nth-child` is not supported by IE8 and below.

Fortunately, jQuery accept unsupported CSS rule. so you can use a polyfill :

```
$('.questions li:nth-child(4n+1), .questions li:nth-child(4n+4)').addClass('white');
$('.questions li:nth-child(odd)').addClass('clr');
```

You'll need to change you CSS to :

```
.questions li{
    width : 50%;
    float : left;
    background:#f00;
}

.questions .white{
    background : #fff;
}
.questions .clr{
    clear : both;
}
```

Comment: Only Javascript, no css3

Comment: @user2191187 and that's why i've put a second solution for compatibility issue.